# How can I get information about malicious ASN ratio of dns?

Tags: python, dns

I have been learning DNS and python. How can I get information about malicious ASN ratio of DNS? Someone help me, please. Thank so much

Comment: Are you talking about something like [this](https://www.spamhaus.org/statistics/botnet-asn/)?

Comment: yea, but I want to get ANS ratio with command line or python.

Comment: What do you mean by ASN ratio? You want to find all the malicious ASNs, and divide that by all the ASNs?